# Primefaces <p:graphicImage /> is throwing undefined function

Tags: function, jsf-2, primefaces, undefined, galleria

```
<p:galleria id="gal" value="#{homeBean.images}" var="image" 
        panelWidth="600" panelHeight="300" >
    <p:graphicImage value="#{image.imagePath}" width="600" height="300" />  
</p:galleria>
```

Problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function galleria.js?ln=primefaces&v=4.0:1
```

And no preview, nothing - like it doesn't exist. But in the source code it does exist.

The generated source code is :

```
<div id="gal" class="ui-galleria ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-galleria-panel-wrapper">
        <li class="ui-galleria-panel ui-helper-hidden">
            <img id="j_idt8" 
                src="/FindHostpital/images/ib-haytham-1.jpg?pfdrid_c=true" 
                alt="" width="600" height="300" />
        </li>
        <li class="ui-galleria-panel ui-helper-hidden">
            <img id="j_idt8" src="/FindHostpital/images/ibn-haytham-2.jpg?pfdrid_c=true"
                alt="" width="600" height="300" />
        </li>
        <li class="ui-galleria-panel ui-helper-hidden">
            <img id="j_idt8" src="/FindHostpital/images/ibn-haytham-3.jpg?pfdrid_c=true"
                alt="" width="600" height="300" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script id="gal_s" type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Galleria','widget_gal',
        {id:'gal',panelWidth:600,panelHeight:300,custom:false},'galleria');});
</script>
```

Comment: did you try making a hard refresh of the page in the browser?

Comment: yes i did thats not the problem, i added a jquery library and it was conflicting with the primefaces one , so it was solved by removing the  added jquery library now it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

i was using a jquery library and it was conflicting with the primefaces jquery library removed the jquery library and i used only primefaces jquery library and it worked just fine