# What does the attribute ?pfdrid_c=true mean in primefaces PDF object

Tags: pdf, primefaces

I read a few posts attaching `?pfdrid_c=true` attribute to a pdf object. What is it for and why would I use that. Related posts using this attribute:

[Primefaces <p:graphicImage /> is throwing undefined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193568/primefaces-pgraphicimage-is-throwing-undefined-function)

[JSF Load uploaded images from nested subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811787/jsf-load-uploaded-images-from-nested-subfolders)

Comment: According [to this](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/index.html?constant-values.html) that parameter sets `DYNAMIC_CONTENT_CACHE_PARAM`. According [to this](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/application/PrimeResourceHandler.java) that variable is used to control the `Cache-Control`, `Expires` and `Pragma` headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/index.html?constant-values.html) that parameter sets `DYNAMIC_CONTENT_CACHE_PARAM`. According to [this](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/application/PrimeResourceHandler.java) that variable is used to control the `Cache-Control`, `Expires` and `Pragma` header